# Grab value of a dictionary that is in an array

Tags: ios, swift, openweathermap

I am trying to grab some values from a dictionary that is in an array and I don't know how I would do this. I was able to grab stuff from a dictionary and from an array but not with them combined. I am using the openweathermap hourly api if that helps at all.

I tried combining the 2 different ways that I have done but that didn't work. Here is what I tried:

```
struct HourlyWeatherAPI: Decoder
{
    let main: Main
    let wind: Wind
    struct Main: Decodable
    {
        let temp: Double
    }
    struct Wind: Decodable
    {
        let speed, deg: Double
    }
}
```

That -^ is at the top of my code and then this is much later

```
if let tempJson = jsonObject["list"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
{
    for eachTemp in tempJson
    {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let result = try decoder.decode(HourlyWeatherAPI.Main.self, from: data!)
        print(result.temp)
    }
}
```

This is some of what is coming out of the API, just the first entry. I am trying to grab the stuff in main:

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.0197,
    "cnt": 96,
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1555196400,
            "main": {
                "temp": 282.26,
                "temp_min": 281.409,
                "temp_max": 282.26,
                "pressure": 1018.06,
                "sea_level": 1018.06,
                "grnd_level": 985.672,
                "humidity": 56,
                "temp_kf": 0.85
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 804,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "overcast clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 100
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 3.99,
                "deg": 313.922
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2019-04-13 23:00:00"
        },
```

Comment: You should make a struct to represent the root level object with at least the `list` property. Then you can decode the `JSON` to that type and access the list

Comment: Unrelated: I think you should tweak the `HourlyWeatherAPI`. For one, it's not an API, it's a data transfer object (DTO). It also doesn't really matter that it's hourly. If there was another weather API that served daily weather summaries, the model object would be pretty much the same. Consider instead: `WeatherSnapshot`, or something along those lines.

Comment: @DennisW. So would I made another one like I already have or change the one that I have?

Comment: I think you need another one, you have the items in the `list` as the `HourlyWeatherAPI` struct but you need a struct that holds the `list`. Something like `struct Root:Codable { let list: [HourlyWeatherAPI] }`

Comment: @DennisW. I added it but it "does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'" when I put it the way you said

Comment: `HourlyWeatherAPI` should conform to `Decodable` not `Decoder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want you data structures to match the JSON that you are receiving, starting with the root level object. Then you can decode the root object and access the contained data structures.

```
struct Root: Decodable {
     let list:[HourlyWeatherAPI]
}

struct HourlyWeatherAPI: Decodable {
     let main: Main
     let wind: Wind
}

struct Main: Decodable {
    let temp: Double
}

struct Wind: Decodable {
    let speed, deg: Double
}

/* 
 * decode your JSON as before, but use the new Root object as the type. You
 * can then access the hourly weather data from the list property
 */
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data!)
let hourlyWeatherList = result.list
let firstWeatherItem = hourlyWeatherList[0]
let temp = firstWeatherItem.main.temp
```

Comment: Then how would I call it? Like to print it out

Comment: The `root` object will contain your `list` of `HourlyWeatherAPI` objects you can access.

Comment: would it be something like: let result = try decoder.decode(Root.init(list: Main), from: data!)

Comment: I added how to access the `list` to the bottom of the answer. You don't need to `init` anything, the `Root` object will contain the `list` of weather items as a property. The `Decodable` protocol will take care of making all the nested data structures for you.

Comment: Ok so now I got it to print after you edited it. How would I just grab like temp or wind speed? Cause right now it is printing it all out

Comment: The `list` is an array of `HourlyWeatherAPI` items, you can use indexing or a loop to access or iterate over the items. Then for each item access the properties `main` or `wind` and similarly their properties. e.g. `main.temp` or `wind.speed`